# Multiple Strange errors with Visual Basic - Failed to set Win32 parent window of the Control

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019, creating a Visual basic Project using "Windows Forms App (.NET)" as the project template.

This happens right after I create the project and haven't added any additional code.  When I try and create a textbox on the form, Visual Studio provides the following error (ERROR 1):

[image: FailedToCreateComponentError]

Also, the following error comes up if I try and drag the control from the ToolBox directly onto the default form (ERROR 2):

[image: ObjectRefrenceNotSet]

The key part of this error from what I can tell is "Failed to set Win32 parent window of the Control."  I was previously trying to create some mobile apps using Xamarin (mentioned this because xmarin had a buggy GUI) however, this is happening after rebooting the machine, starting up visual studio, and creating a project using "Windows Forms App (.NET)" as the project template.  This has worked in the past so it's coincidental it started happening after I was trying to use xmarin in a separate project/solution.

====

UPDATE:
When creating a project template using "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)", with the added "Framework" at the end, I'm able to draw the textbox on the form (First error is not happening).  Still not able to drag directly onto the form.  Still getting the second error "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object".

Not sure what the difference between "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)" and "Windows Forms App (.NET)" is in the project templates.

====

Any help or ideas please let me know.

Jeff

Comment: The .NET Framework option will target .NET Framework 4.8 or earlier. The .NET option will target .NET 5.0, which is the latest version of .NET Core. WinForms support had to be written from scratch in .NET Core so it's not quite there yet, although it's very close to done. There are still some issues though. I would suggest that you try a new project and see whether the same thing happens. If it does, you ought to repair VS as it seems as though something may be corrupt.

Comment: Thank for that info, i'll use the previous version as the app I'm making is pretty basic.  So it seems that if I move the application to the primary monitor (on a laptop, currently using 3 monitors). Then everything works, good to go.  Seems like it may have something to do with the window scaling.  I've tried to restart with window scaling at 100% and other problems emerge (such as not being able to resize the form).

Comment: I have a Surface Pro connected to two 2K monitors via a Surface Dock myself and I do see some visual scaling issues but I've never encountered exceptions like those.

Comment: With that said, I might try the repair.

Comment: I just started seeing the same error message as in your first screenshot. Likely a bug in the .NET Core designer then. I'd suggest reporting it to Microsoft.

Comment: The form was being displayed incorrectly (some artifacts around the edge) on a secondary monitor at the time. I closed the form, moved the VS window to the main screen and opened the form again, then things were OK. I was then able to move the Vs window back to the secondary monitor. I'm now able to add controls and even create new forms without issue.

Comment: I am showing the same, I found that if you drag the Visual Studio window to the main screen then it corrects the problem immediately (no need to close anything).  Still it's pretty annoying.  It has something to do with the DPI and/or window scaling feature.  When I try and drag a control into a form while using a secondary monitor, it errors out.  I think the drag drop function (overly simplified) is returning pixels out of bounds to the form this causing an error.  I'll try and figure out how to report this as it's pretty annoying.

Comment: I create a Windows Forms App (.NET) application and can drag control to the form without errors. Could you provide more details to help reproduce your problem?

Comment: When you do it using a non-primary monitor it causes issues sometimes.  The issue happens when dragging controls onto a form when the visual studio window is on a secondary display.  Also other odd things happen when trying to arrange groups of controls.

Comment: "Automatic scaling is turned off".  That sounds relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by chance.  Really happy this is resolved as it was preventing me from doing more tasks within Visual Studio.  To anyone else that may be having this issue, I am using 3 monitors.  I had these monitors configured to different Scale and Layout Settings.  In doing so, it looks like it confused visual studio whom was trying to use the settings from the primary display.

To resolve this, I set the "Scale and Layout" setting to the same on each monitor.

[image]

I set this back to 100% on each monitor which resolved the issue.

-Jeff

Answer (score 1):

As @Jeff82 and @jmcilhinney noted in the question comments, this appears to be caused by one of, or a combination of, DPI scaling and using Visual Studio on a non-primary monitor. These steps resolved it for me:

1. Close the form on which you're trying to place the control
2. Move Visual Studio to your primary monitor
3. Open the form again

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else running into this error like I have over the last day. If you are moving a WinForm from Framework to .Net 6 the solution is to add the app.manifest file and uncomment the following code.

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
        <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
        <longPathAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">true</longPathAware>
    </windowsSettings>
</application>
```